# Classic ASP loading graphic

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I need to display a loading graphic (whilst sql query runs) during the loading of an asp page.

Have set a graphic to show (animated gif) which shows via response.flush() just after the graphic is referenced and hides via javascipt onload.

All work perfectly except that my AVG antivirus setup (and therefore I expect most others') gets in the way of the buffer flush as presumably it is analyzing the stream of html/javascript, so the page just loads as one lump.

Any thoughts? (or perhaps another way of doing this via classic asp/javascipt?)

Many thanks

Comment: You could load the whole "page" without the data, display a graphic, and fetch the data via AJAX.  Then just hide the graphic after the AJAX operation completes.

Comment: OK thanks  - will look into that

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have a look at the following related questions:

[Loading screen in classic ASP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030101/loading-screen-in-classic-asp-page)

[show loading message while loading contents in asp using jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219755/show-loading-message-while-loading-contents-in-asp-using-jquery-ajax)